# sorting array of type object using Arrays.sort() method

Tags: java, comparison, sorting

I know how to sort an array of objects using Arrays.sort() method in following way.

```
Arrays.sort(array of primitive type);   
Arrays.sort(array of primitive type, from, to); 
Arrays.sort(array of an object type);   
Arrays.sort(array of an object type , from, to);
```

but i have no idea about following two methods.

```
Arrays.sort(array of an object type , comparator);  
Arrays.sort(array of an object type , from, to, comparator);
```

Can someone please let me know how to sort array of type object using these methods.I request you to add code or any link that directs to the .java class.I tried to search it but could not find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  You need to implement a Comparator to use the methods you're asking about.

Comment: It should always be very easy to find the documentation for a given java class.  All you need to do is google `java 7 class-name`.  In this case, google: `java 7 Comparator`.  If you're looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for the `Arrays` class, there are multiple links to the documentation for `Comparator`.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
class Person{  
   int id;  
   public getId(){return this.id;}  
//Other  stuff in your custom class
}  

Person[] persons = ...;//An array of person you get from somewhere
Arrays.sort(persons,new Comparator<Person>(){  
    @Override  
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){  
         return p1.getId() - p2.getId();  
   }  
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy:

Comparator Interface gives you control over the way you sort your Object.

An Object can be based on a key which is your wise.

For example, Account object should be sorted based on the AccountNumber

```
class Account {
    String AccountNumber; //Key 1 
    String AccountName;   //Key 2
    String GovtID;        //Key 3 
}
```

You can sort on either of three keys.

In order to have control on the sorting, you have to define a class that implements the Comparator interface, which will define the logic used for sorting.

```
class SortAccountByNumber implements Comparator<Account> {
    //Implement Unimplemented method 
    @Override
    public int compare(Account a1, Account a2) {
        //Read the specification for this method here in the Java Doc.
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Now to use this, simply call

```
  SortAccountByNumber varSortAccountByNumber = new SortAccountByNumber();
  Arrays.sort(arrayOfAccounts,varSortAccountByNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where the comparator is not defined inline.

Either way is acceptable, but I think this way is easier to understand.

```
class Person {
   int id;  
   public getId(){
       return this.id;
   }  
}

class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person personOne, Person personTwo) {
        reuturn personOne.getId() - personTwo.getId();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Person[] personArray = buildArraySomehow();
PersonComparator pc = new PersonComparator();
Arrays.sort(personArray, pc);
```

Comparator is an interface with only one method: compareTo.

When you create a Comparator, this is the only method you need to implement.

Note that *PersonComparator.compareTo()* does nothing but return the difference of the IDs of the two Person objects.

This is because of how the *compareTo()* method is supposed to work:

- If the first item "*comes before*" the second item, a negative number should be returned.
- If the first item "*comes after*" the second item, a positive number should be returend.
- If the two items are equivalent (in terms of ordering), zero should be returned.

Check out the documentation for [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for more info...

Answer (score 0):

For complex objects Java does not know how to compare them. Thus you need to write an Comparator. Normally you choose a member of the class that has to be compared.

```
public class Comp implements Comparator<Test> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Test t, Test t1) {
       return what_you_want_to_compare;
    }    
}
```